# Wordpress - slashes disappear after uploading project to a server

Tags: php, wordpress, slash, redux-framework

I'm making this website on WP, working with a theme called Ave.
Everything works fine on localhost (using MAMP on Mac), but after I upload it to a web server (to set up a dev) some of the Ave's core plugin slashes disappear, console looks like that:

[image]

Link example: domain.com/wp-contentpluginsave-coreextensionsredux-repeaterrepeaterfield_repeater.css?ver=1552814064

You can see that there are no slashes in this link, therefore the redux options panel doesn't work properly (I can't save anything or so).

Do you guys have any idea what might be the reason?
I can add that I've already tried a clean theme's installation made directly on the server (the same result/doesn't work) and also migrated from one localhost to another (two Macs) and it works properly on both.

EDIT: I also found a place where these particular files are taken from.
[image]

Comment: are there any warnings/notices in the logs? what is the php version on the server and the version in your mamp?

Comment: 7.2 on both, good idea to check 'em, lol

Comment: turned wp_debug on, nothing